java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'tesseract':
Hey i am trying to use tess4j for tesseract and having this issue for intelliJ on Mac.
Tesseract is working when I use terminal but whenever I use tess4J, it throws me this error :
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'tesseract':
dlopen(libtesseract.dylib, 0x0009): tried: 'libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibtesseract.dylib' (no such file),
Thanks for your help
Configuration
file list for dylib

can you manage to use Tesseract from intellij terminal ? If not, did you check if intellij manages to read the correct path variable ?

Tesseract works fine when I don't use Tess4J @драган-јованковић

Did you set the library path for Tess4J?
Run > Edit Configurations and add something like this
-Djava.library.path=/path/to/libtesseract.dylib

I did in vm option yes :
-Djava.library.path=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tesseract/5.4.1/lib/libtesseract.dylib
but I still have the error

You should provide a directory listing so we can see that the library is where you think it is, and a screen shot of the configuration for java.library.path so we can verify that the information is all correct.

@markspace I added screenshots in the post if you can take a look :)

The file list is the same thing as the configuration screen shot, as far as I can see.
